# How to create a Svelte derived store that executes code only when new items are added to an array in another store

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I'm working on a SvelteKit app in which all functionality is based on a list of URLs. Users can add URLs to this list, or remove them.

When a new URL is added, the app fetches the URL and then runs multiple async operations on the fetched data.

I can think of many ways to build this, but I would like to use Svelte [derived stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived), if possible.

- The list of URLs would be stored in a [writable store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable)
- When a URL is added, a derived store runs all required async operations on this new URL (and not on the other URLs) and stores the results.

What's the most Svelte way to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is by using a [custom store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores).
`createStores` returns...

- `.urls` A derived store of type `string[]`
- `.urlResults` A readable store of type `{url: string, value: unknown}[]`
- `.addUrl` A function to add a URL
- `.removeUrl` A function to remove a URL.

`createStore` takes a callback function of type `(url: string, set: (v: unknown) => void) => void` that is run whenever a new URL is added.

```js
import { writable, derived, get } from 'svelte/store';

function createStores(processUrl: (url: string, set: (v: unknown) => void) => void) {
    const urlResults = writable<{ url: string; value: unknown | null }[]>([]),
        urls = derived(urlResults, (all) => all.map((v) => v.url));

    const addUrl = (url: string) => {
        urlResults.update((v) => {
            v.push({ url, value: null });
            processUrl(url, (newValue) => {
                const index = get(urls).indexOf(url);
                if (index > -1) {
                    urlResults.update((current) => {
                        current[index].value = newValue;
                        return current;
                    });
                }
            });
            return v;
        });
    };

    const removeUrl = (url: string) => {
        urlResults.update((all) => all.filter((v) => v.url !== url));
    };

    return {
        urls,
        addUrl,
        removeUrl,
        urlResults: { subscribe: urls.subscribe }
    };
}

export default createStores((url, set) => {
    // Replace with your async actions
    setTimeout(() => set('Proccessed ' + url), 5000);
});
```

Comment: @Bert if you are using this code make sure to change `index > 0` to `index > -1`  (line 11) because if you don't updates will fail on the first URL.